# rails real-time application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, socket.io, real-time

I am building a real-time application ,and I am using private_pub gem based on fayejs 
but it doesn't have a lot of features like pusher ex. presence channels which I can fetch online users 
for me pusher is expensive for my application 
I read some posts about socket.io but I didn't know how to implement it with rails and also if I need to learn node.js before using it 
hope any one could help me

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why exactly it is expensive for your application but I have never found any problem.

Please refer this link.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails/

Comment: You should post answers that do more than provide 'works here' with a link. Those aren't particularly useful, unfortunately.

Comment: @dharin ,actually I am using fayejs because private_pub gem is built based on it ,thanks for your link btw